# "overflow: hidden" alternative to cut off an element that is over a div container

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Is there a way to cut off an element (in this case a banner turned to -45deg) that's out of a div container without using the command "overflow: hidden"? Everything would be fine if the command "overflow: hidden" did not cause jittering on my website. I have prepared a small example here:https://jsfiddle.net/k0fucpqr/

If not, is it possible to create a banner that will be cut at the edges to 45deg and fits right into the corner of the rectangular div container?

I would not ask if I knew how to create such a an element!

```css
body {
  background-color: #123
}

#card {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;/*cuts the corners from "new-banner*/
  width: 320px;
  height: 180px;
}

#banner-pos {
  position: relative;
}

.new-banner {
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #59b0b9 5%, #33777d 95%);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #171a21 !important;
  padding: 2px 40px 1px 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: normal;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin: 16px -32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="card">
  <div id="banner-pos">
    <span class="new-banner">free</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider `clip-path`

```css
body {
  background-color: #123
}

#card {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 4px;*/
  width: 320px;
  height: 180px;
}

#banner-pos {
  position: relative;
}

.new-banner {
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #59b0b9 5%, #33777d 95%);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #171a21 !important;
  padding: 2px 40px 1px 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: normal;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin: 16px -32px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 70% 0%, 88% 100%, 12% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 70% 0%, 88% 100%, 12% 100%); 
}
```

```html
<div id="card">
  <div id="banner-pos">
    <span class="new-banner">free</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use skew transformation *(works only with a bottom or top gradient)*:

```css
body {
  background-color: #123
}

#card {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 4px;*/
  width: 320px;
  height: 180px;
}

#banner-pos {
  position: relative;
}

.new-banner {
  color: #171a21 !important;
  padding: 2px 40px 1px 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: normal;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin: 16px -32px;
  z-index:0;
}
.new-banner::before,
.new-banner::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:38%;
  z-index:-1;
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, #59b0b9 5%, #33777d 95%);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.new-banner::before {
   right:50%;
   transform:skewX(-45deg);
   transform-origin:bottom right;
}

.new-banner::after {
   left:50%;
   transform:skewX(45deg);
   transform-origin:bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div id="card">
  <div id="banner-pos">
    <span class="new-banner">free</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use multiple background on the main container:

```css
body {
  background-color: #123
}

#card {
  background: 
    linear-gradient( 135deg,transparent 4%,#59b0b9 4%, #33777d 8%,transparent 0)
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 4px;*/
  width: 320px;
  height: 180px;
}

#banner-pos {
  position: relative;
}

.new-banner {
  color: #171a21 !important;
  padding: 2px 40px 1px 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: normal;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  margin: 16px -32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="card">
  <div id="banner-pos">
    <span class="new-banner">free</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That' it! Second one works best for me. Thank you very much @TemaniAfif

Comment: Note that `clip-path` only works on SVG elements in IE
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility